# which browsers are mostly used in India for android & ios devices

Tags: android, iphone

which browsers are mostly used in India for android & ios devices for browsing purpose. I need to perform the cross-browser testing with my app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not  related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, compatibility on Chrome and Firefox is the only one that really matters. But, talking about popular browsers, there's UC browser, Opera, Brave browser, etc.

Also, I support the ones who have commented. This isn't a programming question.